# How to solve select 2 widget error on dynamic form in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, dynamicform

This is what the error looks like:

[image]

The error only exists when I use select 2 on dynamic form widget by wbrangca. And also same problem occurs for depdropdown.

Console error:

```
jquery.js:1468 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #salesqty-{$i}-catagory_id
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js:1468)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js:2125)
at Sizzle.select (jquery.js:2546)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery.js:869)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2792)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2909)
at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (create:809)
at fire (jquery.js:3187)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3317)
yii2-dynamic-form.js:90 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
at _parseTemplate (yii2-dynamic-form.js:90)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (yii2-dynamic-form.js:37)
at Function.each (jquery.js:365)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
at jQuery.fn.init.init (yii2-dynamic-form.js:36)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.yiiDynamicForm (yii2-dynamic-form.js:19)
at create:826
at dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
```

And the javascript looks like:

```
var $hasSelect2 = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-select2]');
if ($hasSelect2.length > 0) {
    $hasSelect2.each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var configSelect2 = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-select2'));

        if ($(this).data('select2')) {
            $(this).select2('destroy');
        }

        var configDepdrop = $(this).data('depdrop');
        if (configDepdrop) {
            configDepdrop = $.extend(true, {}, configDepdrop);
            $(this).removeData().off();
            $(this).unbind();
            _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
        }
        var s2LoadingFunc = typeof initSelect2Loading != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
        var s2OpenFunc = typeof initSelect2DropStyle != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
        $.when($('#' + id).select2(configSelect2)).done(s2LoadingFunc(id, '.select2-container--krajee'));

        var kvClose = 'kv_close_' + id.replace(/\-/g, '_');

        $('#' + id).on('select2:opening', function(ev) {
            s2OpenFunc(id, kvClose, ev);
        });

        $('#' + id).on('select2:unselect', function() {
            window[kvClose] = true;
        });

       if (configDepdrop) {
            var loadingText = (configDepdrop.loadingText) ? configDepdrop.loadingText : 'Loading ...';
            initDepdropS2(id, loadingText);
        }
    });
}
```

If I don't use the select 2 widget there will be no error on console.

Comment: Please add more details like: console errors and code

Answer (score 0):

if you still need...
Check for the use of single

> '

instead of

> "